# Ordering rows of a List<int[]> in C#

Tags: c#, list

I have a `List<int[]> sol_iniziale = new List<int[]>();` that have 5 rows of 30 elements each...
I need to order the element of each row in ascendent order.

**The elements to put inside the sol_iniziale are from a file that I read.**
Example:

If I have: `{{2 1 55 23 3}, {44 7 88 2 1}}`

I want as a result: `{{1, 2, 3, 23, 55}, {1, 2, 7, 44, 88}}`

I wrote a function but the output order is not correct...if I have 
`{51, 0, 1, 5, 5, 0},` the output is `{0, 1, 5, 5, 0, 51}` ..I don't understand where the (maybe stupid) error is!

Thank you in advance.

```
void Ordina_sol_iniziale() 
{
    int temp = 0;
    int temp2 = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= nzaini; i++) //5 rows
    {
        for (int y = 0; y <= nogg; y++) //30 elements of each row
        {
            temp = sol_iniziale[i][y];
            temp2 = sol_iniziale[i][y + 1];
            if (temp < temp2)
            {
                sol_iniziale[i][y] = temp;
            }
            else
            { 
                sol_iniziale[i][y] = temp2;
                sol_iniziale[i][y+1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Using Linq: `sol_iniziale = sol_iniziale.Select(l => l.OrderBy(x => x).ToArray()).ToList();`

Comment: you want to sort each array, but you just compare 2 neighbor element. that just shift the first smallest element to the first sit.

Answer (score 1):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<int[]> nums = new List<int[]> { new int[] { 3, 1, 2 }, new int[] { 5, 2, 4 } };
    foreach (var row in nums)
    {
        Array.Sort(row);
    }

    foreach (var row in nums)
    {
        foreach (int i in row) Console.Write(i + " "); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Linq you can do the following:

```
IEnumerable<int[]> res = sol_iniziale.Select(t => {
    Array.Sort(t);
    return t;
});
```

If you want back a List instead of an IEnumerable just do:

```
res.ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use each of the above solutions, or Just correct yours:

```
void Ordina_sol_iniziale() 
{
    int temp = 0;
    int temp2 = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= nzaini; i++) //5 rows
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < nogg; y++) //30 elements of each row
        {
            for (int j = y + 1; j <= nogg; j++)
            {  
                temp = sol_iniziale[i][j];
                temp2 = sol_iniziale[i][y];
                if (temp < temp2)
                {
                    sol_iniziale[i][y] = temp2;
                    sol_iniziale[i][y+1] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recomend you use Linq for something like this. Example:

```
var yourList = new List<int[]>{
                    new int[]{ 2, 1, 55, 23, 3 },
                    new int[]{ 44, 7, 88, 2, 1}
                };

var sorted = yourList.Select(innerList => innerList.OrderBy(elm => elm));
```

Note:

If you want `List<int[]>` out too for some specific purpose, you can include `ToArray()` and `ToList()`:

```
var sorted = yourList.Select(innerList => innerList.OrderBy(elm => elm).ToArray()).ToList();
```

This will select each list, and return it sorted.

Comment: I take the elements of sol_iniziale reading a file, can I apply this method also in my case?

Comment: As I understand it, you are readint the values into a `List<int[]>` and working with that? Then that should not be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're trying to implement bubble sort algorithm, you should use Array.Sort() function.